# Load time weaving of javax.swing.* classes with AspectJ

Tags: swing, aspectj, java

I am using AspectJ to trace calls to graphics class.
So far, I have used a pre-weaved set of javax.swing.* classes and upon loading I tell JVM to use these weaved classes and not the ones from JRE by using -Xbootclasspath/p switch.

I would like to switch to load time weaving mode.
Can anyone help me how to weave javax.swing on load time. I have searched the net but still I cannot figure it out how to do it. I know that by default, AspectJ load time weaver will not weave java.* and javax.* classes. Someone suggested using

-Xset:weaveJavaPackages=true,weaveJavaxPackages=true

in aop.xml but none of this helped because javax.swing classes are loaded before the weaver is attached to the classloader. I guess that the weaver does not see these classes at all.

How can I manage to dynamically weave javax.swing classes? Should I implement a custom class loader that first registers a weaver then does the class loading?

Can someone please suggest any solution?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, only that weaving java and javax classes is very tricky for exactly the reason you say (they are loaded before the weaver is loaded.  A custom class loader may help, but no guarantees.  If at all possible, I'd stick to compile time weaving.

Comment: Indeed it seems to be very hard to weave on load time java boot classes. I have heard that some people have used a custom weaver for this implementation but no one shares any specification on how to do it.

Comment: I agree with the above comments that this is going to be hard to do. Maybe if you tell us why you are trying to accomplish this (ie. what your real problem is) we can provide you with an alternative to weaving.

Comment: As Adrew said, it is tricky because it is a hen vs. egg problem: You need the runtime environment to be loaded before you can run any Java programs (like e.g. the weaving agent), but you need the weaving agent to instrument some JDK/JRE classes. If you post some sample code - ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - I would like to look into it and try something.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can suggest if you need to use `execution()` pointcuts for `javax` packages is to binary-weave the JRE's *tools.jar* and create your own, woven version. I have done that in the past, it worked nicely. But this is only an option if you have control over the runtime environment running your application.

If you do not want to use such an approach, you will have to resort to `call()` pointcuts. This way you can capture calls made by your own application or any 3rd party libraries affected by LTW. Only calls made by JRE classes loaded by the boot classloader will escape your aspect, which should not be too bad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert, but while this looks promising:

[Configuring Load-time Weaving with aop.xml files](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#configuring-load-time-weaving-with-aopxml-files)

Specifically:

```
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    ...
  </aspects>
  <weaver options="-verbose">
    <!-- Weave types that are within the javax.* or org.aspectj.*
         packages. Also weave all types in the foo package that do
         not have the @NoWeave annotation. -->
    <include within="javax.*"/>
    <include within="org.aspectj.*"/>
    <include within="(!@NoWeave foo.*) AND foo.*"/>
    ... 
  </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

I'm not sure how it could work given the `ClassPreProcessor` used by the LTW's agent (although I haven't tried it). Here's the beginning of its `preProcess` method:

```
public byte[] preProcess(String className, byte[] bytes, ClassLoader loader, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain) {
    if (loader == null || className == null || loader.getClass().getName().equals(deleLoader)) {
        // skip boot loader, null classes (hibernate), or those from a reflection loader
        return bytes;
    }
    ...
    try {
        synchronized (loader) {
            ...
            WeavingAdaptor weavingAdaptor = WeaverContainer.getWeaver(loader, weavingContext);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Which makes it pretty clear how boot loader classes are skipped. In addition, the `WeaverContainer.getWeaver()` invocation is what appears to trigger `aop.xml` processing, and that doesn't occur until after a class with a non-null loader is processed.

Not sure how much that helps with an actual solution, but hopefully it sheds some light on why things behave the way they do...

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you are halfway there
Its not that hard, rather pretty straightforward.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <aspectj>
  <aspects>
 <aspect name="com.ciena.EDTCheck"/>
 </aspects>
    <weaver options="-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true -verbose">    
    </weaver>
  </aspectj>
```

Make sure that you have

> aspectjweaver.jar in javaagent like -javaagent:C:\aspectj1.8\lib\aspectjweaver.jar

also make sure that your aop.xml above is in META-INF folder

that's all to run from Eclipse or some IDE

if you want to run from command line make sure that you give -javagaent there too

Comment: Have you actually ever tried and does it work for you? For me it does not.